# Can I use Azure Active Directory to install Exchange locally on a non-domain computer?

Tags: azure, office365, exchange-server, skype-for-business

I would like to move my Exchange and Skype for Business services off of Office 365 and just host them locally, but I want to know if I can use those services on-premise with Azure Active Directory, as I do not want to promote our server to a domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Exchange to a member server (non-DC) but it requires a valid Active Directory Forest to be available.  The member server must be part of a full domain and the administrative accounts installing must have schema update/ enterprise admin roles.

You can create AD servers in Azure and then connect those to 365 if you needed but you wouldn't be able to build random vm's in Azure and not have a dedicated AD.  The Azure default directory won't cut it.  Is that what you're talking about?